# Check if ServletResponse has any content

Tags: java, jsp

How can I check if a response (`ServletResponse`) contains any content without calling the `getWriter()` - method, e. g. in a filter? Or in other words: the filter should only modify the content if there was already written something into the stream:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // Only do that if there is really some content
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

It could happen that the `response.getWriter()` - method might be called later on somewhere else in the code (not in this filter, e. g. for a file-download). In that case, the second call will fail since the stream was already opened...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to extend `ServletResponseWrapper` and use a `CharArrayWriter` internally for writing the response. The `CharArrayWriter` has a `size()` method which will return the size of the buffer. Make sure you pass a wrapped response down the filter chain and you should be able to get the size at any point in the program.

```
public class LengthAwareServletResponseWrapper extends ServletResponseWrapper {

    private final CharArrayWriter out = new CharArrayWriter();

    public LengthAwareServletResponseWrapper(final ServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
    }

    public int getWrittenContentLength() {
        return out.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        return new PrintWriter(out);
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually don't quite understand the idea of not being able to call getWriter twice on the responce-object as long as the stream is not closed. Why is that not possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *not able to call getWriter twice*. Is an exception being thrown?

Comment: I correct: I can't call getwriter() and getOutputStream() on the same response (leads to an IllegalStateException if I remember correctly), I don't quite see why...

Comment: Once you call `getWriter` you cannot call `getOutputStream` and vice versa. It is even stated in the docs http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream(). I'm not sure why that is, but I bet it's a valid reason.